# Python DataFrame append to existing sheet in XLS file (not XLSX)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

I need to put DataFrame to an existing Sheet in an existing XLS file.
I am searching for solution for problem:

```
with ExcelWriter(new_mis, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df_fin_k.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=new_sheet, index=False, startrow=4)
    writer.save()
writer.close()
```

gives

```
openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or
convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.
```

I need to keep xls format, as xlwt

So with code:

```
with ExcelWriter(new_mis, mode='a') as writer:
    df_fin_k.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=new_sheet, index=False, startrow=4)
    writer.save()
writer.close()
```

i get

```
ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlwt!
```

is there any way to append/put dataframe to an existing XLS file?

Comment: Excel .xls file is a binary format and it can't be simple added like csv. You need make another one and rewrite existing file.

Comment: `Openpyxl` does not support XLS.